# Difficulty solving for x.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, logarithms

I was asked,

> Use to substitution $y=a^x$ or otherwise to solve the equation $a^{3x} - 2a^{2x} + a^x = 0$.

I attained the expression,

$y^3 - y^2 + y = 0$ unable to solve further provided the given solution is $x = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$y^3-2y^2+y=y\,(y^2-2y+1)=y\,(y-1)^2$$

Comment: so obvious and i missed it thanks a lot

Comment: Happens :) Have a nice day